# Dynamically create a class and then create a list<dynamicClass> based on it in C#

Tags: c#

I want  to create a class and its properties on run time, the properties will be like Year2001, Year2002, Year2003, Year2004, Year2005... I get these property names on run-time, I get them in a list. Later I need to use this class to create a list which I need to show in the kendo grid.I surfed a lot and thought of using ExpandoObject, but was unsuccessful.

Comment: Do you want to create a class or an object at runtime?

Comment: @msmolcic... I wish to create a class at runtime...

Answer (score 1):

If all properties will be of the form YearX and contain some information about or related to that year, then I would strongly recommend you (if at all possible) to go with something along the lines of an `IList<YearInfo>` where `YearInfo` is some object containing the info you need for every year, including an integer property indicating what year the object corresponds to. If you require these objects to be unique you could use an `IDictionary<int, YearObject>` or `ISet<YearObject>` instead.

Reflection can be powerful, but it it comes at the price of complexity and loss of type safety/compile-time checks. Avoid when possible.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like you are really wanting to a grid with grouping support. Your idea of having the system create a CLASS at runtime is not going to fly. Even if it were possible, which I doubt it is, it is absolutely the wrong approach.

Like I say - have a read about Grouping / Hierarchy on Grid Controls [(Kendo grid example here)](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/hierarchy), and maybe have a look at OLAP cubes as well...

Answer (score 0):

Although you have had some answers I would also like to suggest an alternative way of doing this which is using DataTables. This is the approach I take when I have any "Dynamic" data sets that I want to present to the grid.

This is also the approach that Telerik themselves take with one of their code samples.

here are a couple of links to show them doing this to DataTables and Dynamic Objects

[Grid Binding to Data Table](http://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/binding-to-datatable-0191a594e359)

[Grid Binding to Dynamic Objects](http://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/binding-to-a-collection-of-dynamic-objects)

Personally I find the binding to Tables easier to deal with as I am used to dealing with Data Tables.